# Positioning Materialize CSS switches in a tabular fashion

Tags: html, css, reactjs, materialize

I have encountered with a Materialize Switch alignment issue, hoping you can help with it.
I am trying to align two switch elements so that the switch sliders start at the same x position.
here is a simplified HTML of the elements (each switch is actually a react component):

```html
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 0.3rem;">
  <div>
    <div class="switch">
      <label>Show all products
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="lever"></span>
        Show on sale products only
      </label>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div class="switch">
     <label>Show out of stock products
     <input type="checkbox" checked="">
     <span class="lever"></span>
     Hide out of stock products</label>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The switches are aligned depending on the length of the labels currently, as such:

```
Show all product <-> Show on sale products only

Show of stock products <-> Hide out of stock products
```

While I want it to be displayed in the following way:

```
Show all product       <-> Show on sale products only

Show of stock products <-> Hide out of stock products
```

Appreciate any suggestion you might have.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You just need a small change to your structure and in the `CSS`. I have wrapped label text in `span` tag with class name `.switch-label` and added `min-width` to that element.

```css
.switch .switch-label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 135px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" integrity="sha256-OweaP/Ic6rsV+lysfyS4h+LM6sRwuO3euTYfr6M124g=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 0.3rem;">
  <div>
    <div class="switch">
      <label><span class="switch-label">Show all products</span>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="lever"></span>
        Show on sale products only
      </label>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div class="switch">
     <label><span class="switch-label">Show out of stock products</span>
     <span>
     <input type="checkbox" checked="">
     <span class="lever"></span></span>
     <span class="switch-label">Hide out of stock products</span>
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Viral that is exactly what I need

Comment: @primm Glad to help!